# In Swift, what's the syntax for making a "wrapper" subclass of an unspecified subclass of a given base class?

Tags: swift

This one is driving me nuts since I feel it should be possible, but I just cannot make the compiler happy no matter how I try to express the idea...

I'm working on a SpriteKit project.  One of the classes is a wrapper around SKSpriteNode to add an action that the sprite calls when it's touched:

```swift
class TouchableSprite: SKSpriteNode {
  /// The action to run upon touch
  var action: (() -> Void)? = nil

  /// Make the sprite react to touches
  override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool {
    get { return true }
    set {}
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    action?()
  }
}
```

All well and good.  Now I want to have an SKLabelNode with the same functionality.  Just duplicating the code but with SKLabelNode works, but I figured I should be able to have a generic wrapper that would work for any of the various SKNode subclasses.  So...

```swift
class Touchable<T>: T where T: SKNode { ...
```

Nope, Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'T'.

```swift
class Touchable<T: SKNode>: T { ...
```

Same deal...  Oh, I know!

```swift
class Touchable: T where T: SKNode { ...
```

At least that's a different error: 'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration.

```swift
class Touchable<T>: T where <T: SKNode> { ...
```

No, Closure expression is unused.  After what feels like a zillion different tries, I feel like the world's biggest idiot for having to ask how to write this, but I really want to know.

Oh, I also thought maybe there could something odd about SpriteKit's class hierarchy (because of the dual Swift/Objective C support), so I also tried various permutations with just a pure Swift class.

```
class Base {
}

class Wrapper<T: Base>: T {
}
```

Same array of messages; I just can't get this right.  Can someone please tell me how to express this idea, or at least tell me why it's not possible.

Edit: My current workaround at least for SpriteKit where I have the node hierarchy is to add the wrapper as a parent node:

```swift
class Touchable: SKNode {
  let action: () -> Void

  init(_ child: SKNode, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.action = action
    super.init()
    name = "touchable" + (child.name ?? "")
    addChild(child)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented by Touchable")
  }

  override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool {
    get { return true }
    set {}
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    action()
  }
}
```

Then I make whatever I want to wrap and instead of `addChild(...)` I do `addChild(Touchable(wrapMe) { ... })`.  It's OK, but not quite as clean as I'd like.

Comment: It is impossible to specify a generic type as a superclass. You have to achieve this some other way.

Comment: @Sweeper, is there some Swift documentation where it discusses this restriction?  I'd like to at least understand why it's illegal.

Comment: You call them wrapper classes but neither TouchableSprite nor Touchable is that, they are sub-classes. To create a wrapper class then SKSpriteNode/SKNode would be a property of that class rather than the superclass, something like `class MyWrapper { var myNode: SKSpriteNode}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Swift or ObjC. You're trying to create multiple-inheritance, and that's not allowed. Extensions cannot override methods, so you can't do this through an extension. You can't make a type inherit from both SKSpriteNode and "some other type that provides overrides (i.e. Touchable)." And you can't (safely) insert Touchable into SKSpriteNode's superclass chain (you actually can using the runtime, but don't do that; you can easily break the rest of the system in unexpected ways).

Your "workaround" is actually the correct way to do this. It's not a workaround. It's just composition, and it's good. If you're finding it inconvenient to use, then we can talk about that; it's probably straightforward to improve the calling syntax using extensions if that's a problem.

Comment: I maybe(?) see what you mean. In this case what I'm trying to add is a subclass of a single (currently leaf-level) class and it would become a new leaf level in the hierarchy (which is why the specific versions with direct inheritance from SKSpriteNode or SKLabelNode work).  But if some sort of general syntax was valid, perhaps it would be difficult for the compiler to ensure that I was building a valid single-inheritance hierarchy.